# Nginx reverse proxy with separate aliases

Tags: centos, nginx, python

Interesting question I have this python code:

```
import sys, bottle, gevent
from bottle import *
from gevent import *
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer

@route("/")
def index():
    yield "/"

application=bottle.default_app()
WSGIServer(('', port), application, spawn=None).serve_forever()
```

that runs standalone with nignx infront of it as a reverse proxy.
Now each of these pieces of code run separately but I run multiple of these per domain per project(directory) but the code thinks for some reason that it is top level and its not so when you go to mydomain.com/something it works but if you go to mydomain.com/something/ you will get an error. No I have tested and figured out that nginx is stripping the "something" from the request/query so that when you go to mydomain.com/something/ the code thinks you are going to mydomain.com// how do I get nginx to stop removing this information?

Nginx site code:

```
upstream mydomain {
        server 127.0.0.1:10100 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=10s;
}
upstream subdirectory {
        server 127.0.0.1:10199 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=10s;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        location /sub {
                proxy_pass http://subdirectory/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
                client_max_body_size 10m;
                client_body_buffer_size 128k;

                proxy_connect_timeout 90;
                proxy_send_timeout 90;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;

                proxy_buffer_size 4k;
                proxy_buffers 4 32k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        }
        location /subdir {
                proxy_pass http://subdirectory/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
                client_max_body_size 10m;
                client_body_buffer_size 128k;

                proxy_connect_timeout 90;
                proxy_send_timeout 90;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;

                proxy_buffer_size 4k;
                proxy_buffers 4 32k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out :]

apparently in the proxy_pass you need to tell it the subdirectory just like the request will be:

```
location /sub {
            proxy_pass http://subdirectory/sub; // here the location ie: /sub needs to be passed to the underlieing 
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
            client_max_body_size 10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout 90;
            proxy_send_timeout 90;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;

            proxy_buffer_size 4k;
            proxy_buffers 4 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}
```